# Sendgrid handlebars #if statement in html checkbox

Tags: sendgrid-templates

is it possible to do a replacement inside a HTML tag?

Template:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled {{#if CompleteAndTrueConfirmation}}checked{{/if}} >
```

Test Data:

```
{
    "CompleteAndTrueConfirmation": true
}
```

I get the error:

> Unexpected character after / in tag. Expected >.

[image]

This template works but looks cumbersome:

```
{{#if CompleteAndTrueConfirmation}}
<input type="checkbox" disabled checked />
{{else}}
<input type="checkbox" disabled />
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use a Handlebars block like `{{#if ...` within an HTML start or end tag because it interferes with the HTML parsing in the SendGrid template editor. ☹

More info:

When I edit module HTML, paste your template, and save, I get an error:
[image]

When I edit the code again, I see the code has been modified because the editor tries to fix the HTML by making attributes out of the bits of Handlebars code:
[image]

It *is* possible to do substitution where the test data contains HTML ([example](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#replacement-with-html)), but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a template.